# How to render without rectengles between objects?

Tags: rendering, camera

Helo, maybe someone could help me with my rendering problem? When I render I see strange rectangles bedind the tree and I don't know how to fix this.
[image]

I guess this is not a rare problem, but maybe I could not find the answer or I just don't know how to call this thing.

Comment: Your render result is indeed very strange and no, it's not common. Can you please explain better how your scene is made? Is the background an horizontal plane? Are you using Cycles for the render? (If you can upload your blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit your question with a link, that would help)

Comment: I use horizontal plane with texture and a tree with leaves is made with Sapling Addon. I use Blender Render

Comment: This looks like a bug and should probably be reported to the tracker with a proper example file to recreate the problem